# wget cannot find website

Tags: download, wget

I ran this command to download from the following website, with the `-p` and `-k` options added (See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) for their descriptions.)

```
wget -pk http://www.tomshardware.com/
```

What it returns is

```
...
--2012-11-29 23:32:42--  http://www.tomshardware.com/%3C%25=%20content[i].buildUserPic%20%25%3E
Reusing existing connection to www.tomshardware.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-11-29 23:32:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

And the exit status is 8, indicating that the execution is not successful. Why is it not successful?

Comment: Just tried it myself, and it worked fine.  Something wrong with your DNS, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the default document (index.html or its equivalent depending on the web server) as well as all referenced assets ('A' elements, src attributes of 'IMG' and 'SCRIPT' elements and 'LINK' elements) in that document. 
One of those references is broken (oops) and thus the 404.  In this case it look like some bit of JavaScript that in a browser would be fine but to wget (which doesn't have a JavaScript engine) it is interpreted as a URL which points to a reference that does not exist.

Comment: The references aren't broken exactly. wget is parsing the contents of a `<script type="text/html">` element (used for JavaScript templates) as actual HTML, even though it contains JavaScript snippets in it. For example, the URL from the original post is caused by: `<a href="<%= content[i].buildUserLink %>"`.

Comment: That looks like ASP. Strange to see it on the client

Comment: It's almost like someone forgot to add runsat="server"

Comment: I think the ASP tags are just an arbitrary design decision from the template engine. The template is rendered later with JavaScript: `BOM.Utils.templating.render('systemBuilderTpl', microTemplateParams)`

Comment: If you edit this answer I'll accept your edits. Or you can provide your own answer and I'll up vote it.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer since it changes the meaning a bit.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jason Sperske's answer: since you told wget to download page resources with `-p`, it's getting confused by a `<script type="text/html">` element that the page uses.  This type of script tag is used by some JavaScript template engines. The contents aren't valid HTML (since it needs to be parsed by the template engine first), but wget is trying to parse it and follow what it sees as URLs.

The link `http://www.tomshardware.com/%3C%25=%20content[i].buildUserPic%20%25%3E` is a result of wget trying to visit the URL from:

```
<img class="buildUserPic" src="http://www.tomshardware.com/&lt;%=&#32 content[i].buildUserPic&#32;%&gt;" />
```

So, wget *is* able to find the website, but it's parsing what is basically an arbitrary string, without the script on the site being able to read that string and substitute in the right values to make it valid HTML.

Edit: it looks like there's an escaping error in the template itself (it has &lt;%= instead of <%=) on that particular line, but other lines are fine, and the explanation is the same, I think.